# SQL Server & C# : filter for System.Date - results only entries at 00:00:00

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, filter

I have a connected SQL Server database in Visual Studio and am displaying its content in a grid. I created a dropdown menu with the column names as selectable options and a text field to filter for specific content, e.g., DropDown = "Start" - Textfield = 14.03.2015 = Filter Column "Start" for each entry that contains "14.03.2015" - and display it in the Grid.

I'm basically done with that part. The only problem left that I'm facing is whenever I enter a date - e.g., 14.03.2015 it only displays dates which start at 00:00:00 - the other entries that do not start at 00:00:00 are ignored and I can't figure out how to modify this to work properly.

The Grid looks like this: http://abload.de/img/untitled123yqkyn.png

And I am using the following C# code to filter:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FilterExpression = string.Empty;

    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("Start"))
    {
        FilterExpression = string.Format("Start  = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("End"))
    {
        FilterExpression = string.Format("End  = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("Creation Time"))
    {
        FilterExpression = string.Format("DateTimeCreated = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("Last Modified"))
    {
        FilterExpression = string.Format("LastModifiedTime = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        FilterExpression = string.Concat(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, " Like '%{0}%'");
    }

    SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Clear();
    SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add(new ControlParameter(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, "TextBox1", "Text"));
    SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = FilterExpression;
}
```

Excuse the quality of the code, I'm completely new to C# and for that matter programming itself. I hope that there is someone able to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cast statement on your date fields to remove the time portions as follows:

```
FilterExpression = string.Format("CAST(Start  AS DATE) = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
FilterExpression = string.Format("CAST(End    AS DATE) = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
FilterExpression = string.Format("CAST(End    AS DATE) = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
FilterExpression = string.Format("CAST(LastModifiedTime   AS DATE) = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
```

Also if your inputs are dates, then try this:

```
FilterExpression = string.Format("CONVERT(date,Start) = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
FilterExpression = string.Format("CONVERT(date,End) = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
FilterExpression = string.Format("CONVERT(date,End) = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
FilterExpression = string.Format("CONVERT(date,LastModifiedTime) = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
```

Last but not least, if your inputs are varchar, then try this:

```
FilterExpression = string.Format("CONVERT(varchar,Start,101) = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
    FilterExpression = string.Format("CONVERT(varchar,End,101) = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
    FilterExpression = string.Format("CONVERT(varchar,End,101) = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
    FilterExpression = string.Format("CONVERT(varchar,LastModifiedTime,101) = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. When i put this code into my datafields like so:  <asp:BoundField DataField="Start" HeaderText="Start" SortExpression="Start" CAST(Start  AS DATE) = '{0}'/> i get all sorts of warnings and a parser error when compiling. Am i missing something?

Comment: It should be done like this:
    FilterExpression = string.Format("CAST(DateTimeCreated AS DATE) = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);

Comment: Hi, thanks. When inserting your snippet i get the error: The expression contains undefined function call CAST(). - when executing the my code.

Comment: Copy and paste your code here.  The Cast needs to be in quotes because it is a SQL function not C#.

Comment: Hi, this is my C# code: http://pastebin.com/TK0abXTs - and this is my gridview http://pastebin.com/yTmSq4nC

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your effort. It's appreciated. When i insert FilterExpression = string.Format("CONVERT(date,Start) = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);  - into the first if-statement i get the error message: Cannot find column [date].